# Flattening a directory

Tags: batch-file

Suppose the following directory structure

```
my_script.bat
Dir1
   File1.txt
Dir2
   Dir3
      File1.txt
```

I want to flatten it so that I have just one directory, where each filename is prefixed with all of its parent directories below the current directory (where my batch file is sitting).

So flattening the above list would produce something like

```
Dir1-File1.txt
Dir2-Dir3-File1.txt
```

Or just some way to identify which folder it came from, doesn't necessarily have to be hyphenated.

Can this be done with a windows batch file? Or maybe there is already a command for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to give credit to [Jacob Seleznev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115272/jacob-seleznev) for the original idea, but here's a solution which also includes the path in the new filename:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%F in (*) do (
    set _name=%%~fF

    rem Change the path to a relative path by replacing the current folder with ""
    set _name=!_name:%cd%\=!

    rem Replace slashes with hyphens
    set _name=!_name:\=-!

    copy "%%F" ".\!_name!"
)
```

Output:

```
Dir1-File1.txt
Dir2-Dir3-File1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for /r %F in (*) do set name=%~pfF
set name=%name:\=-%
echo %name%
```

Comment: I can opt to use the directory part of the full path as the prefix, but is there a way for me to replace slashes with a different delimiter?

Comment: To replace a substring with another string use the string substitution feature. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, string substitution will be useful.