# Unflattening a directory structure based on filenames

Tags: batch-file

This is the inverse of the "flatten" operation described in this question: [Flattening a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032503/flattening-a-directory)

I would like a batch script that will go through each file in a "flattened" directory and put them back into their original directories, creating the directories as necessary

So if the following files were in my folder:

```
images-nature-dcim001.jpg
images-nature-dcim002.jpg
images-dcim003.jpg
images-indoors-dcim004.jpg
```

It would produce the resulting directory structure, creating the directories and moving (or copying) the files into the correct folder.

```
images
  dcim003.jpg
  nature
    dcim001.jpg
    dcim002.jpg
  indoors
    dcim004.jpg
```

Note: the example uses hyphens to separate the directories, but they can be any character.

Comment: Actual examples of the filenames will help provide a robust solution.

Comment: @foxidrive I am not sure what you mean, but I have updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works here.  It creates the four files at the top and then moves them.

```
@echo off
type nul >images-nature-dcim001.jpg
type nul >images-nature-dcim002.jpg
type nul >images-dcim003.jpg
type nul >images-indoors-dcim004.jpg

for %%a in (*.jpg) do call :routine "%%a"
pause
goto :eof
:routine
set "a=%~1"
set "b=%a:-=\%"
for %%b in ("%b%") do (
md "%%~pb" 2>nul
move "%a%" "%%~pb\%%~nxb"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%cd%") DO SET "precur=%%~dpa"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d *.txt') DO (
    SET "fname=%%~fa"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET "nname=!fname:%precur%=!"
    SET "nname=!nname:\=-!"
    ECHO REN "!fname!" "!nname!"
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the version I am using based on foxidrive's approach to getting the directory name. I didn't think of simply replacing delimiters with back-slashes.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Directory Unflatten
rem //   recursively unflattens directories
rem //   and prepends the directory name to
rem //   the filename

rem // Configuration options
rem // * Files to search for
set pattern=*jpg;*.png  
rem // * Directory name delimiter
set delim=-

rem // Perform moving
for %%X in (%pattern%) do (
  set A=%%X

  rem // Replace delimiter with back-slash
  set b=!A:%delim%=\!

  rem // Not sure how to clean this up
  for %%B in ("!b!") do (
    if not exist %%~pB (
      md "%%~dpB"
    )
    move "!A!" "%%~dpB%%~nxB"
  )
)
```